nvim + ALE: how to change messages color
I've just started using neovim. After installation of ALE plugin, error and warning messages are displayed, but errors are in red and it looks bad on black background (I use nvim for python, mostly). I want to keep the background black, but change the color of error messages. How to do it?
I have already tried all this, to no avail:
" colors for error highlighting:
" highlight ALEError ctermfg=15 guifg=#FFFFFF
" highlight ALEError ctermfg=cyan guifg=#FFA500

" highlight ALEError ctermbg=DarkMagenta
" let g:ale_set_highlights = 0
" highlight ALEError ctermfg=160 guifg=#FF0000
" highlight ALEWarning ctermfg=214 guifg=#FFAA00

(I tried to change the colors without comments, of course, later I commented out those lines, since they had no effect.)
PlugStatus:
- lightline.vim: OK
- tagbar: OK
- vim-fugitive: OK
- vim-rhubarb: OK
- ale: OK
- vim-gitgutter: OK
- codeium.vim: OK
- vim-easy-align: OK
- nerdtree: OK
- vim-commentary: OK

nvim --version:
NVIM v0.6.1
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org

System info:
Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon
Cinnamon version: 6.0.4

Thanks in advance for help.
